# LSTM loss function and backpropagation

Tags: lstm, rnn, training, backpropagation

I'm trying to understand the connection between loss function and backpropagation.
From what I understood until now, backpropagation is used to get and update matrices and bias used in forward propagation in the LSTM algorithm to get current cell and hidden states.
And loss function takes the predicted output and real output from the training set.
But which part is the training part of the LSTM?
Are they somehow connected ?
What is the training objective for the LSTM model?

Answer (score 1):

- For sake of convenience, I'll go in ascending order of how the neural
  network is working

  - The forward propagation of the LSTM cell is where the input is fed  ->  passed through the hidden states  ->  output is achieved (either at each time-step or at the end depending upon the type of problem
    like classification, forecasting, etc.,)
  - Then after receiving the output the error between the actual value and the predicted value is calculated. This is where the loss
    function comes into the picture
  - Classification problem - cross-entropy/log-likelihood
  - Regression Problem - Mean Squared Error, Mean Absolute Error functions are used.
  - So, after calculating the error only we backpropagate through time (BPTT) in case of RNN neural networks which updates weights of the
    matrices and cell states of the LSTM cells. In practice, we refer to
    these backpropagation algorithms as optimization algorithms like
    Gradient Descent, etc.,
  - The optimization algorithms like RMSProp, Adam are much faster in practice than the standard gradient descent algorithm.

  Overall, the training part of any neural network algorithm is that at
  the early stages of training, it will perform very horribly and over
  a period of time, with the correct loss function and backpropagation
  algorithm it will try to reduce the chances of classifying error and
  will converge fast depending upon the backpropagation algorithm used.